# Display category name according to current session language in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a project for online store with 3 languages, in the database I have fields with the category names for each language for example EN, RU, UA. what I want to achieve is to show category name for the current user selected language. Currently I have the code below to show category name

```
<div class="featured-category-item-slider">
    @foreach($categories->where('is_featured','=',1) as $cat) 
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 sc-common-padding">
                <a href="{{ route('front.category',$cat->slug) }}">
                        @if(Session::has('language'))
                            <div class="left">
                                <h5 class="title">{{ $cat->name }}</h5>
                           </div>
                        @endif
                </a>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

The above shows me the default category name in EN, I can do the "if" ''elseif'' logic. I need to first put the current session language in a variable so I can use it to compare and show category name based on the current session language. Something like this "$language=session language", then I can use $language to compare, like this "if $language =='RU' show category name in RU"
Please help, thanks

Comment: Why you don't use laravel Lang/Translate instead ?

Comment: And it doesn't need to store language in session; you can use `app()->getLocale()`. but it may need to some changes in your routes/urls.

Comment: @ArashYounesi I have a Lang/Translate, the category names are store in DB as name_en, name_ru, I need to display them according to the current session language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if else logic is not a good choice. if you do not need to change css classes use this solution:

```
@php
    $lang = Session::get('language');
@endphp
```

`<h5 class="title">{{ $cat->name_{$lang} }}</h5>`

Comment: thanks a lot, it was the session get that I needed to put in a variable, I had to use the if else to compare, if there is a better way please let me know see my answer below

Comment: @dbcooper. I think `@switch` can be better way. you can use it instead of `@if`

Comment: thanks I have updated my answer with the switch statement

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Arash Y answer I was able to resolve the issue, many thanks.
I ended up with the code below

```
@php
$lang = Session::get('language');
@endphp
@switch($lang)
  @case(1)
     <div class="left"><span class="title">{{ $cat->name_ukr }}</span></div>
  @break
  @case(2)
     <div class="left"><span class="title">{{ $cat->name }}</span></div>
  @break
  @case(3)
     <div class="left"><span class="title">{{ $cat->name_eng }}</span></div>
  @break
  @default
     <div class="left"><span class="title">{{ $cat->name }}</span></div>
@endswitch
```

Used switch statement as suggested by @Arash Y.
Hope this helps someone in the future.